# Max value of a Series in a single Dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe where each row contains a Series in a *single* column.

```
             col1    
row1     [34,55,11,8]
row2     [36,76,69,6]
row3     [77,31,40,55]
row4     [51,41,26,30]
```

I want to get the max of each value in the series and produce that in a new column.

```
        col1                   max 
row1     [34,55,11,8]          55
row2     [36,76,69,6]          76
row3     [77,31,40,55]         77
row4     [51,41,26,30]         51
```

**My attempt**:

```
df['max'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x:x.max())
df.head()
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

Comment: Some of your rows have an *empty* series.

Comment: Define a function that considers the empty-series case and returns NaN instead of that lambda

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. That makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dataframe constructor re-create your `list` type columns

```
df['Max']=pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist(),index=df.index).max(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A small mistake in your code. The same could be achieved by the following:

```
df['max']= df['values'].apply(lambda x: max(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have easy method for this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[34,36,77,51],'B':[55,76,31,41],'C':[11,69,40,26],'D':[8,6,55,30]})
df
```

[image]

```
df['MMax'] = df.max(axis=1)
df.MMax
```

[image]